# How to pick a research question broad or narrow one?

Tags: phd

I am a PhD student of computer science ( senior year ). I have worked on problems given by my senior collegues in the past. Now I am at a stage where I have to pick a new research problem. I have tried to read as much as possible about particular topic, but still facing difficulty in picking a new problem. I have find out few research problem, but they seems to special cases. I am good with solving special case not a broad problem.

Question : Should I pick a research problem with broad or narrow one (special case )

Comment: Are you going into a PhD (i.e. in your "senior year" of an undergrad degree) or are you currently a PhD student? If the latter, it seems a bit late to be picking a research topic if you are in your "senior year" of a PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Real broad/general problems are of course nice, because they apply to many situations. However, what students consider broad/general problems are often ill defined problems or problems that would require an unreasonable amount of time and resources to answer. So beware, that your broad problem is really a broad problem and a realistic problem.

After that is just a matter of finding the most interesting problem you can come up with, that is solvable with the time and resources you have available. (Remember to multiply your best estimate of the time it will take by two.)

That is very broad advise, but we cannot give you more detailed help on that as we don't know your skill level, the resources you have, the time you have available, and most of us are not an expert in your field. Your advisor on the other hand (should) know all that. So come up with a couple of problems, list the pros and cons, your estimate of the time and resources needed to complete these, and ask your advisor for his or her opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A PhD is about specializing in many regards. Your dissertation should lead to a specialization.

I think you will also find it much easier to write about a narrow question as opposed to a broad one. Choosing too broad of a research question is actually one of the common reasons I see for PhD students languishing in the "candidacy" phase of the PhD. They can give a good overview in their prospectus/proposal, but then cannot pin down the specifics to a point where they actually can write a focused dissertation. Unless you are going to write a dissertation that is so revolutionary that it can encompass and change a broad discipline, I am of the opinion that a narrower research question is far more likely to lead to a successful dissertation.